# Error de iteracion

Tags: python

Estoy estudiando lo basico de Python, y tengo que hacer un ejercicio que diga:
Escribir funciones que dada una cadena de caracteres:
a) Imprima los dos primeros caracteres.
b) Imprima los tres últimos caracteres.

Al A, lo resolvi de esta manera:

```
def primeros2(x):
    cadena=x
    print(cadena[0]+cadena[1])
    
primeros2("hola")
```

Y al B, de esta manera:

```
def ultimos3(y):
    cadena=y
    print(cadena[-1] + cadena[-2] + cadena[-3])

ultimos3("enciclopedia")
```

EL problema esta, en que de la manera en que resolvi el item 3, esta bien el resultado, pero no es la manera correcta, es necesario utilizar un ciclo For, por lo tanto, lo intente resolver de la siguiente manera:

```
def ultimoss3(y):
    num = 3
    longitud = len(y)
    for i in longitud:
        print(longitud[i]-3)

ultimoss3("enciclopedia")
```

Y al ejecutar, hay un error de interacion. Se que quizas es relativamente "facil" para algunos, pero estoy intentando aprender Python, que a mi se me hace dificil. ¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Los tres últimos caracteres de una cadena "x" los puedes obtener con rebanada de listas: `x[-3:]`.

Comment: Corrige el título. Querías decir "iteración" (de "iterar", o repetir) y no "interación" de interaccionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si sea de tu agrado hacerlo sin el **for**, de esta manera:

```py
def primeros2(x):
    cadena=x
    print(cadena[0:2])
    
primeros2("hola")

def ultimos3(y):
    cadena=y
    print(cadena[-3:])

ultimos3("enciclopedia")
```

solo debes tener en cuenta que se puede imprimir varios elementos usando 2 puntos dentro de la supuesta posición del elemento, ejemplo:

```py
cadena = "hola"
print(cadena[1:]) # [desde : hasta]
```

La salida sería:

> ola

En caso de que imprimas **cadena[2:]** la salida sería:

> la

ya que le indicas que imprima desde la posición **2**, el cual es el tercer elemento de la cadena, en caso de que pongas **cadena[1:3]**, las salida sería:

> ol

Empieza desde la posición **1** hasta la posición **3**, restándole **1**, es decir, imprime el elemento de la posición 1 y 2.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que es lo que esta pasando, vale al querer tu iterar un objecto int, te marca un error diciendo que int no es un objeto iterable.

La funcion "len" te regresa la longitud de tu variable "y" (cuantos caracteres, items, etc.. conforman tu objeto).

Lo que tendrias que hacer para iterar una longitud o un numero entero seria crear un rango de 0 hasta el numero que te ha regresado la funcion len

en este caso seria asi:

```
for i in range(len(longitud)):
    print(i)
```

Ten en cuenta que la iteracion empieza desde 0, si quieras que empezara de un cierto numero seria agregarlo de esta manera.

```
for i in range(1, len(longitud)):
    print(i)
```

De esta manera empiezas desde el numero 1

Fuente:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias. Pero como devolveria los ultimos 3 caracteres?